# Java.net.ProtocolException

Tags: java, android, delphi

I have next procedure to rename file on google drive, using REST with Google api. It's working with Delphi xe7.

Unfortunately with RAD 10 this procedure raise an exeption:

> **Java.net.ProtocolException unknown method 'Patch'...** . I've read that it's because of java libraries. I changed paths
>   *Tools-options-sdk manager - java* to XE 7 java libraries, but it's useless.

Don't want to play Russian Roulette with random changing/updating setting, can someone tell me, what i should exactly update/change in RAD settings. 
Thank you.

```
procedure ServerPatchDriveFile;
var
Folder  : TJSONObject ;
FolderDest, itemmm   : TJSONObject ;
parents:  TJSONArray ;
begin

 form2.RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.AutoUpdate := false;
 form2.RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
 form2.RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
 form2.RESTClient1.AutoCreateParams:=false;
 form2.RESTClient1.Accept:= '';
 form2.RESTClient1.ContentType:= '';
 form2.RESTRequest1.Method:= rmPATCH;
  Form2.RESTClient1.BaseURL:='https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FileId}';
  form2.RESTRequest1.Resource := '';
  form2.RESTRequest1.Params.AddUrlSegment('fileId', UntitledId);

  Parents:= TJSONArray.Create;
  itemmm := TJSONObject.Create;
  itemmm.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('id', form2.EditIdFOlder.Text));
  Parents.AddElement((itemmm));

    Folder:= TJSONObject.create;
    Folder.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('title', 'Myfile'));
    Folder.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('parents', Parents));
    form2.RESTRequest1.AddBody(Folder);
try
  form2.RESTRequest1.Execute;
except
on e: Exception do
begin
  ShowMessage(e.Message);//Show Exception
end;
end;

Folder.free;
Application.ProcessMessages;

end;
```

Comment: can you show the full Java stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @mjn
Rest request failed: java.net.ProtocolEception: Unknown method 'Patch'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE]

![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/0wlJbsN)

<img src="http://imgur.com/0wlJbsN" width="296" height="210">